# Rails: list column name if true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I've got a pretty standard `Preferences` table. I'd like to list all true booleans for each record therein. How would I go about that? I know that `Preference.column_names` will give me all, but I need each record's particular `true` settings. Any idea? Something like

```
@preference.column_names do |c|
  c if c = true
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want the names of all the boolean columns in `@preference` that value a `true` value?

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: what value does column_names have, is it serialized? give example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the general idea of looping through an objects attributes with the attribute name and value.  Are you having to filter out only boolean fields?  Or are all the fields boolean?

```
@preference.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value|
  "#{attr_name} is #{attr_value}" if attr_value == true
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Got a bit of filtering to do: it's an association model and there are IDs in there I don't need out of this loop.

Comment: See edit... that should work.

Comment: And if you just want the names then something like `trues = @preference.each_with_object([]) {  |k, v, a| a.push(k) if(v == true) }` should do the trick.

Comment: `each_with_object` doesn't seem to work for me? Although that method seems neatest.

Comment: @emm: I missed some parentheses, you want the block to look like `{ |(k,v),a| ... }` for the `each_with_object` trickery.

Comment: The only downside to this is that the keys in `attributes` don't always match up with the table's columns. That's not likely to be an issue though.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to know the boolean columns, something like this should give you their names:

```
booleans = Model.columns.select { |c| c.type == :boolean }.map(&:name)
```

Then you can use `send` to extract the values based on a name and a simple "is it `true`" test takes care of the rest:

```
trues = booleans.select { |name| @preference.send(name) == true }
```

Comment: This works well, too. Don't know which is more efficient now.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about efficiency for something like this, the differences will almost certainly be too small to worry about and the expensive parts of your code will probably be elsewhere. Go with the approach that is clearest and most readable to you, that way you won't be wondering what the code is doing when you come back to it in six months.